# Session value in knockout

Tags: javascript, asp.net, knockout.js

In my viewModel i want to get the current session value. For that i have written like this :

```
self.currentUserId = ko.observable(HttpContext.Current.Session["UserID"]);
```

But its showing me error that

```
ReferenceError: HttpContext is not defined.
```

How to define HttpContext? OR Is there any way to get current session value?

Comment: What technology do you use? Webforms or MVC? What is your view engine: aspx, razor? Your ko viewmodel is inlined in your view or it is in a separate js file?

Comment: I am using webforms with aspx view engine. My viewmodel is in separate js file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your statement

```
self.currentUserId = ko.observable(HttpContext.Current.Session["UserID"]);
```

To 
**If your application using webform and viewmodel is inline with aspx page**

```
self.currentUserId = ko.observable('<%=HttpContext.Current.Session["UserID"]%>');
```

**if MVC with razor view engine with inline viewmodel of view**

```
self.currentUserId = ko.observable('@HttpContext.Current.Session["UserID"]');
```

and **if your viewmodel is in external js file, then first store it in a js variable and use in that js**

like, you can't use `HttpContext.Current.Session["UserID"]` in external js file.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src='<path_of_knochout.js>'></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var userId = '<%=HttpContext.Current.Session["UserID"] %>';
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src='<your_view_model_js>'></script>
```

in `<your_view_model_js>` file use

```
self.currentUserId = ko.observable(userId);
```